# Datadog CI for synthetic tests github action fails

Tags: testng, github-actions, datadog

I have some Datadog synthetic api tests.

I have created a API key and an APP key.

Also, I use the official simple github action
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/datadog-synthetics-ci

But when I run the workflow i get this

```
Run DataDog/synthetics-ci-github-action@v0.3.1

(node:1461) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
Error: Running Datadog Synthetics tests failed.
```

and when i try with version 0.2.0 i get this

```
Run DataDog/synthetics-ci-github-action@v0.2.0
(node:1522) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
 ERROR: unable to obtain test configurations with search query 
Error: Running Datadog Synthetics tests failed.
```

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
datadog_site: us5.datadoghq.com
```

and it run as it was supposed to.